# kotlin/js cant run develpment run

Tags: kotlin-js

[image]

i can't run a freshly created kotlin react project when i try to i get see below error en cant use it

```
> Task :kotlinNpmInstall

warning workspace-aggregator-c22f0aa7-62f6-4cd1-b73e-254168ec2f14 > untitled1 > webpack-dev-server > sockjs > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

warning workspace-aggregator-c22f0aa7-62f6-4cd1-b73e-254168ec2f14 > untitled1 > webpack-dev-server > url > querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.

warning "workspace-aggregator-c22f0aa7-62f6-4cd1-b73e-254168ec2f14 > kotlin-wrappers-kotlin-react-router-dom-js-ir > react-router-dom@5.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=15".

warning "workspace-aggregator-c22f0aa7-62f6-4cd1-b73e-254168ec2f14 > kotlin-wrappers-kotlin-styled-js-ir > styled-components@5.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "react@>= 16.8.0".

warning "workspace-aggregator-c22f0aa7-62f6-4cd1-b73e-254168ec2f14 > kotlin-wrappers-kotlin-styled-js-ir > styled-components@5.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>= 16.8.0".

warning "workspace-aggregator-c22f0aa7-62f6-4cd1-b73e-254168ec2f14 > kotlin-wrappers-kotlin-styled-js-ir > styled-components@5.3.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-is@>= 16.8.0".

warning "workspace-aggregator-c22f0aa7-62f6-4cd1-b73e-254168ec2f14 > kotlin-wrappers-kotlin-react-redux-js-ir > react-redux@7.2.6" has unmet peer dependency "react@^16.8.3 || ^17".

warning "workspace-aggregator-c22f0aa7-62f6-4cd1-b73e-254168ec2f14 > kotlin-wrappers-kotlin-react-dom-js-ir > react-dom@17.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "react@17.0.2".

warning "workspace-aggregator-c22f0aa7-62f6-4cd1-b73e-254168ec2f14 > kotlin-wrappers-kotlin-react-router-dom-js-ir > react-router-dom > react-router@5.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@>=15".

warning "workspace-aggregator-c22f0aa7-62f6-4cd1-b73e-254168ec2f14 > kotlin-wrappers-kotlin-react-router-dom-js-ir > react-router-dom > react-router > mini-create-react-context@0.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0".

error An unexpected error occurred: "EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, symlink 'D:\\projects\\kotlin\\untitled1\\build\\js\\packages_imported\\kotlin-test-js-runner\\1.5.31' -> 'D:\\projects\\kotlin\\untitled1\\build\\js\\node_modules\\kotlin-test-js-runner'".

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Which path is your project in? The `]` character in the path of the symlink looks suspicious to me...

Comment: the path to my project is D:\projects\kotlin]\untitled1. tried renaming it, it didn't help